# Get datetime format from string python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, format

In Python there are multiple DateTime parsers which can parse a date string automatically without providing the datetime format. My problem is that I don't need to cast the datetime, I only need the datetime format.

Example:
From "2021-01-01", I want something like "%Y-%m-%d" or "yyyy-MM-dd".

My only idea was to try casting with different formats and get the successful one, but I don't want to list every possible format.

I'm working with pandas, so I can use methods that work either with series or the string DateTime parser.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do expect to match e.g. ```01``` to either month or day?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `pandas`, this is achieved by `pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.guess_datetime_format`

```py
from pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing import guess_datetime_format

guess_datetime_format('2021-01-01')

# '%Y-%m-%d'
```

As there will always be an ambiguity on the day/month, you can specify the dayfirst case:

```py
guess_datetime_format('2021-01-01', dayfirst=True)
# '%Y-%d-%m'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see which one suits best for you:

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

df['Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column']).dt.date

df['Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column']).dt.normalize()
```

the datatype of first two options will be object;

while the 3rd one with normalize will be datetime.

Comment: This isn't addressing what was asked, though. They're wanting to *get* "%Y-%m-%d", for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, I am not sure though.

```py
for col in  df.select_dtypes(include['datetime64']).columns.tolist():
    df[col] = df[col].astype(str)
```