# Identify all date combinations?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I recently took over an ongoing research project and, much to my dismay, it appears our undergrad research assistants have not been following our coding guidelines regarding date entries. Minimal working example as follows,

```
import pandas as pd
MWE = [["05/2003"], ["10/1998"], ["1/4/2014"], ["12/09/1979"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(MWE)
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'year'})
```

There are a few odd ball entries, ie. "Sept 12, 2005" and "20221204", but from what I can see the majority of entries appear to either follow `%m%y`, `%d%m%y`, or `%m%d%y` format.

1. With over 10k lines of data, is there any way to quickly identify all the different date formats? My initial approach has been `print(df["year"].value_counts())` and manually comb through the data to spot all the variations. It seems a bit tedious and imagine there is a better approach? (I'm also coming to Python from Stata and it's a bit of a learning curve.)
2. Ideally we'd like to retain both the month *and* year, so I'm not sure the best solution. At a bare minimum, if we wanted to extract at least the year I suppose I could use `df['year_only'] = df['year'].str[-4:]` where applicable, although that will obviously cause issues in those cases where the last four digits do not constitute the year.

Any thoughts or suggestions on how to approach this predicament would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you expect to tell `%d%m%y` and `%m%d%y` apart? "12/09/1979" could be in either order. "Try to parse it and go through the outliers" seems like an ok approach. But the data will probably always be at least partially bad.

Comment: if these are simply stored as strings and not datetime data (yet), you'll need another heuristic to tell some dates apart _"ISO 8601 was published on 06/05/88 and most recently amended on 12/01/04."_ https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: There is no real way of knowing whether 1/4/2014 means the first of April or the fourth of January unless you have some extra data to work with. Is there any extra data you could use to conclude this? Maybe you could use the assistant's location to determine the date format they are likely used to? This probably wouldn't be perfect, but it would work in most cases.

Comment: Ah, good point -- I didn't even think about that!

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible approaches might be to obtain a pandas Series from your dataframe and apply a suitable regular expression identifying the dates you meet in the entries by using the contains method:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70879159/16343464) a way to identify the probable datetime format from a string. However, in your case, there is a strong ambiguity with dates like `1/4/2014` or `12/09/1979` that are both valid `D/M/Y` and `M/D/Y`.

I would recommend to parse with different formats (using just `dayfirst=True`/`dayfirst=False` is a good starting point, you can then add other formats). In a second time, check if the two day positions can yield different valid dates, you might want to analyze those manually (if you know which student filled which date, you can maybe identify the used format).

```
s1 = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], dayfirst=True)
s2 = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], dayfirst=False)
#s3 = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%m/%Y')

df['ambiguous'] = s1!=s2
df['date'] = s1.fillna(s2)#.fillna(s3)
```

Output:

```
         year  ambiguous       date
0     05/2003      False 2003-05-01
1     10/1998      False 1998-10-01
2    1/4/2014       True 2014-04-01
3  12/09/1979       True 1979-09-12
```